# reflect sprite over x axis and y axis depending on position of other sprite

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

im trying to figure out why my reflect over y axis isnt working

in my gameViewContoller i have the scene set with

```
scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill
scene.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
scene.size = skView.bounds.size
```

then in my gameScene

```
location2 = touch.locationInView(self.view)

var xloc : Int = Int( screenWidth / 2)
//output is 187
var yloc : Int = Int( screenHeight / 2)
//output is 333
var x: Int = Int(location2.x)
// from left to right is 1 - 374
var y: Int = Int(location2.y)
// from top to bottom is 1 - 666
```

i then do the math

```
var zx1 = x - xloc
var x1 = xloc - zx1
   //output when position.x = 10 the x1 is 364    
var zy1 = y - yloc
var y1 = yloc - zy1
  // output when position.y = 10 the y1 is 656
```

then i convert these to cgpoints and move one sprite to the corresponding location

```
var y2: CGFloat = CGFloat(y1)
var x2: CGFloat = CGFloat(x1)


bot2.position = CGPointMake(x1, y2)
```

the bot is always reflected over the y axis but for some reason it wont reflect over the x axis the numbers all add up but something is wrong during the bot position y

thanks for your help

Comment: dont totally get what youre trying to do with these conversions.. but one tip is that in UIKit, the y axis is from top to bottom.   in spritekit the y axis goes from bottom to top.  that trips a lot of people up coming from traditional iOS applications

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `touch location` in an `SKScene` should be calculated using `locationInNode` not `locationInView`. This is because the `origin` of `SKScene` is at the bottom left corner and origin of `UIView` is at the top left corner.

```
var location2 = touch.locationInNode(self)
```

Comment: Ahh surprised I missed that